# How to push complex legacy logs into logstash?

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

I'd like to use ELK to analyze and visualize our GxP Logs, created by our stoneold LIMS system.
At least the system runs on SLES but the whole logging structure is some kind of a mess.

I try to give you an impression:

```
Main_Dir
 | Log Dir
     | Large number of sub dirs with a lot of files in them of which some may be of interest later
 | Archive Dir
     | [some dirs which I'm not interested in]
     | gpYYMM <-- subdirs created automatically each month: YY = Year ; MM = Month
        | gpDD.log <-- log file created automatically each day. 
     | [more dirs which I'm not interested in]
```

**Important**: Each medical examination, that I need to track, is completely logged in the gpDD.log file that represents the date of the order entry. The duration of the complete examination varies between minutes (if no material is available), several hours or days (e.g. 48h for a Covid-19 examination) or even several weeks for a microbiological sample. Example: All information about a Covid-19 sample, that reached us on December 30th is logged in ../gp2012/gp30.log even if the examination was made on January 4th and the validation / creation of report was finished on January 5th.

Could you please provide me some guidance of the right beat to use ( I guess either logbeat or filebeat) and how to implement the log transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash file input:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Main Dir/Archive Dir/gp*/gp*.log"
  }
}
```

Filebeat input:

```
- type: log
  paths:
    - /Main Dir/Archive Dir/gp*/gp*.log
```

In both cases the path is possible, however if you need further processing of the lines, I would suggest using at least Logstash as a passthrough (using beats input if you do not want to install Logstash on the source itself, which can be understood)